# What plants would do good in Central America vivarium, on coco fiber substrate?

Tags: plant-recommendations, terrarium

I made a vivarium and I'm looking for plants that could live happily there. Conditions will be:

- Temperature 22°C to 35°C / 72F to 95F; there will be a hot end and a cold end
- Humidity around 40%, once in a while up to 80%
- Light moderate to low, simulating forest floor and understory
- Substrate coconut fiber + coconut husk chips; *I can add something to it if needed*
- Drainage made of LECA covered with agrotextile that leaks water but may be hard for roots to pierce
- Baby snake playing inside, so sturdy plants preferred
- Happy population of springtails and isopods to clean up after the snake, so something they won't eat too fast, or something that regrows fast